# Storing data in neo4j graph DB

Tags: php, html, neo4j, neo4jphp

I've written a simple HTML code for a form:
**`Form code`**

```
<form method="POST" action="/ducks" novalidate>

            <div class="form-group @if ($errors->has('name')) has-error @endif">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Somebody Awesome" value="{{ Input::old('name') }}">
                @if ($errors->has('name')) <p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('name') }}</p> @endif
            </div>

            <div class="form-group @if ($errors->has('email')) has-error @endif">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="text" id="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="super@cool.com" value="{{ Input::old('email') }}">
                @if ($errors->has('email')) <p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('email') }}</p> @endif
            </div>

            <div class="form-group @if ($errors->has('password')) has-error @endif">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" name="password">
                @if ($errors->has('password')) <p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('password') }}</p> @endif
            </div>

            <div class="form-group @if ($errors->has('password_confirm')) has-error @endif">
                <label for="password_confirm">Confirm Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="password_confirm" class="form-control" name="password_confirm">
                @if ($errors->has('password_confirm')) <p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('password_confirm') }}</p> @endif
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit!</button>

        </form>
```

**`php code`**

```
<?php
        $formdata = Neo4j::makeNode();
        $formdata->setProperty('frname', 'fname')
        ->setProperty('lsname', 'lname')
        ->setProperty('pname', 'pword')
        ->setProperty('mail','email')
        ->save();
        $formdataId = $formdata->getId();
    ?>
```

And I've added a migration code as shown above. Controllers are good, I think so. 
But the data isn't getting stored in neo4j DB. How can I fix it?

Comment: Anybody here who can answer this?

Comment: can you post more code ? like your client setup, what is Neo4j:: ?

Comment: Check the edited question. Neo4j is a graph DB, kind of NOSQL technique. `Neo4j::` is a class, it is invoked with the function `makeNode()`

Comment: Where is the data from the form going? I don't see any mention of POST data in your PHP code?

Comment: @Bulk: Well... I'm kinda beginner in neo4j, can you write a proper php script for me?

Comment: @QWERTYking can you post your controller code?